# How do I access an ArrayList I've initialized in the constructor in another method of that class?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, constructor

Here is a copy of the code, I want to be able to fill the `ArrayList` `userList` with the sample data that is created in the `addSampleData()` method.

```
UserGroup(){
    ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
}

public void addSampleData() {
    User user1 = new User("U1", "admin", "a");
    User user2 = new User("U2", "admin", "b");
    User user3 = new User("U3", "editor", "c");
    User user4 = new User("U4", "editor", "d");
    User user5 = new User("U5", "editor", "e");
    User user6 = new User("U6", "user", "f");
    User user7 = new User("U7", "user", "g");
    User user8 = new User("U8", "user", "h");
    User user9 = new User("U9", "user", "i");
    User user10 = new User("U10", "user", "j");

    for(int i = 1; i<11; i++) {
        userList.add(getUser(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a field of the class (declare it in class scope) instead of declaring it locally in the constructor.

```
class UserGroup {
    ArrayList<User> userList;

    UserGroup(){
        userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    }

    public void addSampleData() {
        // ...
        for(int i = 1; i<11; i++) {
            userList.add(getUser(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some examples? I'm sure that will be very helpful for beginners.

Comment: Better, awesome!

Comment: As I'm not OP I can only up- or down-vote it. You may move the comment to the question, mentioning OP.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `userList` in the class.

Then simply say `userList = new ArrayList<User>();` in the constructor.